# Launch multiple ExecutorService Java

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I want to launch two ExecutorService at the same time.

For example, in my main:

```
MyClass.firstAsync();
MyClass.secondAsync();
```

and,

```
public void firstAsync() {
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
    service.submit(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
            while (true) {
                System.out.println("I m running : First Async");
         }
    });
}
```

then

```
   public void secondAsync() {
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
        service.submit(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
            while (true) {
               System.out.println("I m running : Second Async");
              }
         });
    }
```

The problem is: when the second class is called, it takes the place of the first. So i have this output:

```
I m running : First Async
```

while the second ExecutorService is'nt launched but I have this output

```
I m running : Second Async
```

when the second is launched.

I also tried to put them on the same service (have two service.submit(...) on the same ExecutorService) but it doesn't work at all

**What I want is the both outputs, at the "same time".**

Thank you,
Clément.

Comment: Why do you need two separate thread pools in the first place?

Comment: I neither understand your question; nor the problem that might be behind your idea/request.

Comment: My program is like that. The first function does not do the same thing as the second (in my real main)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "same time"? Can you post the output that you expect and the one that you are getting instead?

Comment: Something like: 

"I m running : First Async
I m running : First Async
"
.......

while the second function isn't called

and then a battle of 

"I m running : First Async
I m running : Second Async"

Comment: Why do you use the Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4). It reserved 4 Threads but you use only 1 (of the 4).

Comment: Re, "when the second class is called, it takes the place of the first"  Nothing that you have showed us could explain that behavior, but you haven't showed us the whole program.  Edit your post to show a complete program that other people can run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot expect to control the execution of the Threads. 
If you want to simulate it, let's introduce in your loops:

```
Thread.sleep(10);
```

This forces the current running Thread to sleep, and gives a chance to the other threads to execute.

But do not expect to orchestrate the execution of the thread.

Comment: Ok. But my two functions, in reallity, listen to a server some information. So I need the both function to be aware about what the server want to say.

The problem is that the first function have a blocking status, and the second too. So I need to separate this functions and I need this functions to be launched everytime, without blocking the other function

Comment: Clement, do you have only one Core on your machine? Otherwise as you run on different Threads, they both run at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works as intended. I am assuming you expecting to get such an output:

```
I m running : First Async
I m running : Second Async
I m running : First Async
I m running : Second Async
```

But instead you get:

```
I m running : First Async
I m running : First Async
...
I m running : First Async 
I m running : Second Async
I m running : Second Async
...
I m running : Second Async
I m running : First Async
...
I m running : First Async
I m running : Second Async
...
I m running : Second Async
```

And maybe you're getting so much output from one thread that you do not see the output from the other.

This happens because both threads compete for access on the same output stream (System.out), and everytime one has access it manages to print multiple lines (maybe thousands) before the other thread gains the permission over the stream.

To test this, add a delay in your loops, so each thread has time to print only one line at a time.

```
while (true) {
    System.out.println("I m running : First Async");
    Thread.sleep(100);  // <---- and surround with try-catch
}
while (true) {
    System.out.println("I m running : Second Async");
    Thread.sleep(100);  // <---- and surround with try-catch
}
```

Comment: That's not really my problem. My problem is: when the second async function is launched, the first is closed, like by magic!

Comment: @ClémentB If the first one is truly closed, and you are not misinterpreting the output, then the code you posted does not include the problem causing this. Try using delays and if they don't work post more code

Answer (score 0):

(1) Your code is okay (save for some minor remarks below), the problem is simply that the actual code is too fast to notice concurrency! Moreover, println is usually synchornized.  If you replace each "run()" with some loop that prints multiple lines you'll notice the concurrency.

(2) I would consider two fixes, regardless:
(a) Do you really need 2 separate thread pools? It's okay if you do, it's just that the reason isn't clear from the example (b) I don't see much sense in instantiating a thread pool as a local method variable, it should be placed where it can be re-used + monitored + terminated sometime. Obviously you might have just simplified the code for the sake of discussion...

Comment: I also tried on the same ExecutorService but it doesn't work too :/

Comment: I actually copied and ran you code (as is, without my suggested changes to executor management). I just changed the single "println" into a loop of a 100 "println"'s... and it worked just fine, yielding a mixed output. Did you actually try it? As I mentioned, you won't see any concurrency with one 'println'....

Comment: @See my final answer :) Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to make a comment, but apparently I need 50 reputation on stackoverflow to comment (resonable, but unfortunate.). So I am going to attempt to answer this question.

The ExecutorService is intended to be a managment object that implements the Executor Interface, this means it can hold a threadpool in it. A threadpool can be used to host varied Runnable thread objects. They dont have to be of the same type.

So for instance, if you had a Runable class with a particular function, you can launch that from a thread held by the ExecutorService because the threads are generic. If you are requiring to identify specific threads to interact with them later, you can have a specific, immutable identifier class field with a getter method in each Runnable thread type. Or if you want you can store reference to the thread object when you construct it.

Alternatively, there is also the ability to find running threads/thread groups and their IDs. you can see this method here:

http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2008/04/java_tip_how_list_and_find_threads_and_thread_groups#GettingThreadGroups

The Answer to your Question is that you should not need to have two ExecutorServices. As you can size your thread pool in a static or dynamic manner and your threadpool can host hetrogeneous thread objects.

I hope this helps. And I hope this is an adequate answer.

Comment: Okay, just saw all the other answers. Could you possibly keep the Executors (if you really do need them) as class fields without storing them locally in your methods?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my final answer.

In my firstAsync() code, there was a NullPointerException that was NEVER displayed in the console.

I putted more than one hour with a guy from my service to figure it out. It's my bad.
Your answer were all good, and my question was stupid.

Thank's, Clément.